# Allow .json upload file in WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want to upload .json files in my media library in WordPress. The reason for this is that I'm using lottie animations and the output is an animated .svg file. I just want to retrieve the file url from the backend to use it in the frontend. Unfortunately .json doesn't work to import even with the usage of the following code:

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mime_types = array(
        'svg'     => 'image/svg+xml',
        'json'     => 'application/json',
    );
    return $mimes;
   }
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');

define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

Does anyone knows a solution for this kind of problem?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you're declaring the new mime types in `$mime_types` but don't do anything with it, instead you're returning the original unchanged `$mimes`.

---

As for your working solution, you could use only one function as follows:

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['json'] = 'application/json';
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Comment: Thank you, now I feel stupid that I haven’t recognized that issue 

Comment: This is almost correct, only PHP determines the mime type of json files to be text/plain, and so in practise this doesn't work. The answer by @MarcGuay has the correct code that works.

Answer (score 5):

Since PHP determines the mime type of json files to be `text/plain` (see [here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099686/why-is-php-not-returning-correct-mime-for-json-files)) the correct solution is:

```
function my_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['json'] = 'text/plain';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_mime_types');
```

Comment: I'd like to testify that this answer works with `text/plain` whereas the selected answer with `application/json` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I just added two different functions instead of an array and for some reason it worked.

```
function json_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['json'] = 'application/json';
    return $mimes;
   }
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'json_mime_types');

function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
   }
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
``
```

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone, neither the `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` constant or the `upload_mimes` filter will work on their own if you are using WordPress Multisite where the list of allowed file types for your sub-sites needs to be declared first within the ‘Network Admin’ -> ‘Settings’ page within WordPress. Obviously your WordPress user needs sufficient privs in order to be able to see this settings page.

In my experience, once you've added `json` to this list, the `upload_mimes` filter will work as expected.